# How to put the digits of a number into an integer array?

Tags: java, algorithm

In my AP computer science class, we are working on an algorithm assignment. We may only use the data types `boolean`, `double`, and `int`. We can not use any of Javas classes for data types or their math library (in other words, we have to build everything from the ground up). I already have working methods that determine the amount of digits a given integer has (`length(int)`), and one that calculates power (`power(double base, int exponent)`). I believe those will be needed for the one algorithm I'm stuck on. The algorithms description is listed below:

> Write a method findDigit (int num, int n) that returns the nth digit from the right of a given 
>   integer where n is a positive integer. For example,
>    findDigit (30568,2) will return 6,
>    findDigit(234,5) will return 0,
>    findDigit(-4532,3) will return 5

I was going to use the string class until I realised I wasn't allowed to. This has to be done using only math operations. If one of you  could give me the logic on how to make an array that contains the digits of an integer, I'll be good to go from there. I would prefer logic over code (so I can get practice writing it), but code in either c++ or java is fine as well.

I had some code that I thought would work, but ended up not working. I can provide it if you would like to look at it if needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: you can do this with just integer division and mod operators.

Comment: And the numbers in which you are finding digits is base 10...

Comment: FlareCat, why do you accept an answer that returns incorrect results?

Comment: @Andreas It looked right enough to me. I can modify it in my code to work correctly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is some pseudocode:

```
int findDigit(int num, int n) {

  for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    num = num / 10;
  }

  return num % 10;
}
```

Comment: You can check with an initial condition if `10 ^ (n-1)  >  num` so that for big `n` values you don't loop all the iterations (return 0 immediately). Just for perfomance. If you always control the value of `n`, don't check it.

Comment: I didn't think Stack Overflow was supposed to be a "do my homework for me" site.  This isn't pseudocode - this is Java, with a single easily-fixed compile error.  You're not helping OP by doing the assignment for them.

Comment: FYI for other people reading this answer. It does not return the correct result for all inputs. Question listed 3 sample inputs, and this answer fails for 33% of them.

Answer (score -2):

I am showing you the process. Here is the code(using c# and .net framework library)

```
private int findDigit(int num, int n)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        int unsigned = Math.Abs(num);    //To get th absolute value of num
        string str = unsigned.ToString();//Convert the (absolute value) to string
        int index = str.Length - n;      //Index of the desired digit

        try
        {
            result = str.Substring(index, 1);     
        }
        catch
        {
            result = "0";
        }

        int digit = Convert.ToInt32(result);  //To Convert the result into int

        return digit;
    }
```

Comment: OP already said that `ToString()` is not allowed: *"I was going to use the string class until I realised I wasn't allowed to."*

Comment: without the ToString() method it is not possible to get the length of the int or index of the digit in c#. so I can't help you.

Comment: @Pavel I find that extremely difficult to believe.  I'm not a C# programmer, but I suspect you'll find that it _does_ support division and modulus operations.

Comment: It is not impossible. It is very possible in C, C++, C#, VB, Java, Python, Scala, Perl, JavaScript, Assembler, or just about any programming language out there.